# Refresh Material Table After Updating Data

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an angular (with asp.net web api) app to insert and update data which is listed inside mat table. when i click on the edit button a dialog box open and i can edit desired values. but the problem is when i click on save popup closes and table not updating.

here's my ts file

```
save() {
    this.form.value.id = this.id;
    this.service.updateEntry(this.id, this.form.value).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.dialogRef.close(data);
      this.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(() => { this.service.getAll(); } );
    });    
  }
```

and here's my service

```
getAll(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
  }

updateEntry(id, entry){
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl+'/'+id, entry)
  }
```

on initialize

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<EntryElement>(data as EntryElement[])
    })
  }
```

and to update the entry

```
updateEntry(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    this.dialog.open(UpdateEntryComponent, {
      data: {
        Id: entry.Id,
        Description: entry.Description,
        IsExpense: entry.IsExpense,
        Value: entry.Value
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: where is mat table?

Comment: @joyBlanks i have added the datasource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way it so use afterClosed() observable

```
updateEntry(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
    this.dialog.open(UpdateEntryComponent, {
      data: {
        Id: entry.Id,
        Description: entry.Description,
        IsExpense: entry.IsExpense,
        Value: entry.Value
      }
    }).afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.service.getAll().subscribe((data) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<EntryElement>(data as EntryElement[])
      })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a common issue with the mat table, If you're datasource is updating but not the table

```
const temp =  JSON.stringify(data);
data = JSON.parse(temp)
```

Have you tried this

Comment: I did but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Please have a check if you are using **dataSource**, is it  updating.

If not updae
 this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(*res*);

Where *res* is the getAll result

Comment: datasource added on initialize